# Is there a way of finding index by content without loop in bash

Tags: bash

I am wondering if there is a simple solution (one line command of sed or awk) of finding index by content in bash. For example, array=(a b c d e), given a target element "d", how can I get its corresponding array index of 3 without looping through the array and comparing each element with the target?

Comment: Use an associative array instead in bash 4+.

Comment: What's wrong with looping through the array? Anything you do will have that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
array=(a b c d e)
declare -p array | grep -Po '\[\K[^\]](?=\]="d")'
```

or with sed:

```
array=(a b c d e)
declare -p array | sed 's/.*\[\([^\[]\)\]\+="d".*/\1/'
```

Output with grep and sed:

```
3
```

---

With a variable:

```
array=(a b c d e)
target="d"
index="$(declare -p array | grep -Po '\[\K[^\]](?=\]="'"$target"'")')"
echo "$index"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you mind explain a little bit about the regular expression?

Comment: Sorry, that would go beyond the scope. I suggest: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)